# Boost.Python: How to expose std::unique_ptr

Tags: python, c++, c++11, unique-ptr, boost-python

I am fairly new to boost.python and trying to expose the return value of a function to python.

The function signature looks like this:

```
 std::unique_ptr<Message> someFunc(const std::string &str) const;
```

When calling the function in python, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: std::unique_ptr<Message, std::default_delete<Message> >
```

My function call in python looks like this:

```
a = mymodule.MyClass()
a.someFunc("some string here") # error here
```

I tried to expose the std::unique_ptr but just cant get it to work..
Does someone know how to properly expose the pointer class?
Thanks!

**Edit:**
I tried the following:

```
class_<std::unique_ptr<Message, std::default_delete<Message>>, bost::noncopyable ("Message", init<>())

;
```

This example compiles, but I still get the error mentioned above.
Also, I tried to expose the class `Message` itself

```
class_<Message>("Message", init<unsigned>())

        .def(init<unsigned, unsigned>()) 
        .def("f", &Message::f)
;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In short, Boost.Python does not support move-semantics, and therefore does not support `std::unique_ptr`.  Boost.Python's [news/change log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/news.html) has no indication that it has been updated for C++11 move-semantics.  Additionally, this [feature request](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7711) for `unique_ptr` support has not been touched for over a year.

Nevertheless, Boost.Python supports transferring exclusive ownership of an object to and from Python via `std::auto_ptr`.  As `unique_ptr` is essentially a safer version of `auto_ptr`, it should be fairly straight forward to adapt an API using `unique_ptr` to an API that uses `auto_ptr`:

- When C++ transfers ownership to Python, the C++ function must:

  - be exposed with CallPolicy of [`boost::python::return_value_policy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_value_policy.html) with a [`boost::python::manage_new_object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/manage_new_object.html#manage_new_object-spec) result converter.
  - have `unique_ptr` release control via `release()` and return a raw pointer
- When Python transfers ownership to C++, the C++ function must:

  - accept the instance via `auto_ptr`.  The [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#ownership) mentions that pointers returned from C++ with a `manage_new_object` policy will be managed via `std::auto_ptr`.
  - have `auto_ptr` release control to a `unique_ptr` via `release()`

---

Given an API/library that cannot be changed:

```cpp
/// @brief Mockup Spam class.
struct Spam;

/// @brief Mockup factory for Spam.
struct SpamFactory
{
  /// @brief Create Spam instances.
  std::unique_ptr<Spam> make(const std::string&);

  /// @brief Delete Spam instances.
  void consume(std::unique_ptr<Spam>);
};
```

The `SpamFactory::make()` and `SpamFactory::consume()` need to be wrapped via auxiliary functions.

Functions transferring ownership from C++ to Python can be generically wrapped by a function that will create Python function objects:

```cpp
/// @brief Adapter a member function that returns a unique_ptr to
///        a python function object that returns a raw pointer but
///        explicitly passes ownership to Python.
template <typename T,
          typename C,
          typename ...Args>
boost::python::object adapt_unique(std::unique_ptr<T> (C::*fn)(Args...))
{
  return boost::python::make_function(
      [fn](C& self, Args... args) { return (self.*fn)(args...).release(); },
      boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::manage_new_object>(),
      boost::mpl::vector<T*, C&, Args...>()
    );
}
```

The lambda delegates to the original function, and `releases()` ownership of the instance to Python, and the call policy indicates that Python will take ownership of the value returned from the lambda.  The `mpl::vector` describes the call signature to Boost.Python, allowing it to properly manage function dispatching between the languages.

The result of `adapt_unique` is exposed as `SpamFactory.make()`:

```cpp
boost::python::class_<SpamFactory>(...)
  .def("make", adapt_unique(&SpamFactory::make))
  // ...
  ;
```

Generically adapting `SpamFactory::consume()` is a more difficult, but it is easy enough to write a simple auxiliary function:

```cpp
/// @brief Wrapper function for SpamFactory::consume_spam().  This
///        is required because Boost.Python will pass a handle to the
///        Spam instance as an auto_ptr that needs to be converted to
///        convert to a unique_ptr.
void SpamFactory_consume(
  SpamFactory& self,
  std::auto_ptr<Spam> ptr) // Note auto_ptr provided by Boost.Python.
{
  return self.consume(std::unique_ptr<Spam>{ptr.release()});
}
```

The auxiliary function delegates to the original function, and converts the `auto_ptr` provided by Boost.Python to the `unique_ptr` required by the API.  The `SpamFactory_consume` auxiliary function is exposed as `SpamFactory.consume()`:

```cpp
boost::python::class_<SpamFactory>(...)
  // ...
 .def("consume", &SpamFactory_consume)
 ;
```

---

Here is a complete code example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// @brief Mockup Spam class.
struct Spam
{
  Spam(std::size_t x) : x(x) { std::cout << "Spam()" << std::endl; }
  ~Spam() { std::cout << "~Spam()" << std::endl; }
  Spam(const Spam&) = delete;
  Spam& operator=(const Spam&) = delete;
  std::size_t x;
};

/// @brief Mockup factor for Spam.
struct SpamFactory
{
  /// @brief Create Spam instances.
  std::unique_ptr<Spam> make(const std::string& str)
  {
    return std::unique_ptr<Spam>{new Spam{str.size()}};
  }

  /// @brief Delete Spam instances.
  void consume(std::unique_ptr<Spam>) {}
};

/// @brief Adapter a non-member function that returns a unique_ptr to
///        a python function object that returns a raw pointer but
///        explicitly passes ownership to Python.
template <typename T,
          typename ...Args>
boost::python::object adapt_unique(std::unique_ptr<T> (*fn)(Args...))
{
  return boost::python::make_function(
      [fn](Args... args) { return fn(args...).release(); },
      boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::manage_new_object>(),
      boost::mpl::vector<T*, Args...>()
    );
}

/// @brief Adapter a member function that returns a unique_ptr to
///        a python function object that returns a raw pointer but
///        explicitly passes ownership to Python.
template <typename T,
          typename C,
          typename ...Args>
boost::python::object adapt_unique(std::unique_ptr<T> (C::*fn)(Args...))
{
  return boost::python::make_function(
      [fn](C& self, Args... args) { return (self.*fn)(args...).release(); },
      boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::manage_new_object>(),
      boost::mpl::vector<T*, C&, Args...>()
    );
}

/// @brief Wrapper function for SpamFactory::consume().  This
///        is required because Boost.Python will pass a handle to the
///        Spam instance as an auto_ptr that needs to be converted to
///        convert to a unique_ptr.
void SpamFactory_consume(
  SpamFactory& self,
  std::auto_ptr<Spam> ptr) // Note auto_ptr provided by Boost.Python.
{
  return self.consume(std::unique_ptr<Spam>{ptr.release()});
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<Spam, boost::noncopyable>(
      "Spam", python::init<std::size_t>())
    .def_readwrite("x", &Spam::x)
    ;

  python::class_<SpamFactory>("SpamFactory", python::init<>())
    .def("make", adapt_unique(&SpamFactory::make))
    .def("consume", &SpamFactory_consume)
    ;
}
```

Interactive Python:

```python
>>> import example
>>> factory = example.SpamFactory()
>>> spam = factory.make("a" * 21)
Spam()
>>> spam.x
21
>>> spam.x *= 2
>>> spam.x
42
>>> factory.consume(spam)
~Spam()
>>> spam.x = 100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    None.None(Spam, int)
did not match C++ signature:
    None(Spam {lvalue}, unsigned int)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I will try this as soon as possible, but the code looks good!

Comment: And what about std::unique_ptr which is defined as add_property. Do I have to wrap it on class definition, where I am adding actually property or defining to_python_converter would be a better practice ?

Comment: The best explanation I have come across on how to pass ownership from Python to C++

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to get the raw pointer from the `std::unique_ptr` container with `get()`. You will have to careful to keep the `unique_ptr` in scope for for whole time that you wish to use the raw pointer value, otherwise the object will be deleted and you'll have a pointer to an invalid area of memory.

Comment: could you add a small example please?

Comment: Try this `auto return_value = class_<std::unique_ptr<Message, std::default_delete<Message>>, bost::noncopyable ("Message", init<>());`

`Message *msg_ptr = return_value.get();`

Answer (score 1):

Boost supports `movable semantics` and `unique_ptr` [since v.1.55](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html).
But in my project I used previous version and made such simple wrapper:

```
class_<unique_ptr<HierarchyT>, noncopyable>(typpedName<LinksT>("hierarchy", false)
, "hierarchy holder")
    .def("__call__", &unique_ptr<HierarchyT>::get,
        return_internal_reference<>(),
        "get holding hierarchy")
    .def("reset", &unique_ptr<HierarchyT>::reset,
        "reset holding hierarhy")
    ;
```

to create `unique_ptr<HierarchyT>` as Python `shierarchy` and pass it to the function that accepts it by reference.
Python code:

```
hier = mc.shierarchy()
mc.clusterize(hier, nds)
```

where C++ function is `float clusterize(unique_ptr<HierarchyT>& hier,...)`.
Then to access results in Python make a call `hier()` to get the wrapped object from the unique_ptr:

```
output(hier(), nds)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think nowadays there is no way to do what you are looking for... The reason is because `std::unique_ptr<Message> someFunc(const std::string &str)` is returning by value, which means one of two things:

1. The return value is going to be copied (but [unique_ptr is not copyable](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/12/quick-q-a-unique-ptr-is-not-copyable-so-why-can-i-return-one-by-value-stack));
2. The return value is going to be moved (now the problem is that boost::python doesn't provide support to move semantics). (heyy, I'm using boost 1,53, not sure in the newest versions);

Is someFunc() creating the object? In case YES, I think the solution is to create a wrapper, in case NO, you can return by reference:

```
std::unique_ptr<Message>& someFunc(const std::string &str)
```

expose the class:

```
class_<std::unique_ptr<Message, std::default_delete<Message>>, boost::noncopyable>("unique_ptr_message")
    .def("get", &std::unique_ptr<Message>::get, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>())
;
```

and also the functions:

```
def("someFunc", someFunc,  return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot change anything in the library. The function is creating the object (it is calling another function which creates the object)